# Expression expected when passing list to another activity

Tags: java, android, list, android-studio

I have two separate activities, Listenpage and PlaylistService. When I run a method in playlist service, I need it to run this line:

```
ListenPage listenPage = new ListenPage();
listenPage.updateLeftList(List<String> LeftPlaylist);
```

and call this method in my Listenpage activity.

```
public void updateLeftList(List<String> LeftPlaylist){
        if (_listenPageSongAdapter != null && LeftPlaylist != null) {
            _listenPageSongAdapter.updateMusicList(LeftPlaylist);
        }
```

Unfortunately (List LeftPlaylist shows errors: expression expected. I dont know why this error is showing up, and nothing i do seems to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You miss a close bracket.

Comment: Where using `List LeftPlaylist` ?

Comment: first create List<String> LeftPlaylist or add items to it then pass like : 
listenPage.updateLeftList(LeftPlaylist);

Comment: I add items to List LeftPlaylist in my Playlist Service Class. I am using a SQLite database to keep track of songs in the playlist and i add songs like this: `db.addsong(new LeftPlaylist(test, "AC/DC"));`